# Pandas Strip text from cell

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am trying to strip text from my dataframe. Currently I have the following:

```
ID                 name
T1548              Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism
T1548.002          Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism: Bypass User Account Control
T1548.004          Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism: Elevated Execution with Prompt
T1548.001          Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism: Setuid and Setgid
T1548.003          Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism: Sudo and Sudo Caching
T1134              Access Token Manipulation
T1134.002          Access Token Manipulation: Create Process with Token
```

If it contains a ': ' I want to remove it and all the text before it and get the following output:

```
ID                 name
T1548              Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism
T1548.002          Bypass User Account Control
T1548.004          Elevated Execution with Prompt
T1548.001          Setuid and Setgid
T1548.003          Sudo and Sudo Caching
T1134              Access Token Manipulation
T1134.002          Create Process with Token
```

Is there a way to strip text like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on the `:` and take the last value.  Using `.str` will apply to the entire column, where `-1` index returns the last value, even if there is only one.

```
df.name.str.split(':').str[-1]
```